# PHP Request URI not passing full querystring

Tags: php, variables, request-uri

I'm having a simple issue that I just can't seem to figure out what's going wrong.

In my script, I'm capturing the current page address using this code:

```
$return_link = 'https://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

If I `echo $return_link`, it returns the correct URL:

```
https://sub.mysite.com/schedule?m=02&y=2015
```

However, when I pass the $return_link variable to a script and redirect to that link, it's dropping the second half of the query string.  So I'm getting this:

```
https://sub.mysite.com/schedule?m=02
```

Can't quite figure out why I'm losing the `&y=2015` portion.

Comment: First things, remove the **constants**. `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` == `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

Comment: "when I pass the $return_link variable to a script and redirect to that link", so how do you exactly do this?

Comment: You are already stating `$return_link` is what you expect, so the issue is between there and the location you are having the problem. You will need to supply that code.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up.  It appears to be happening when I insert the variable into some Javascript:  `setTimeout('window.location = "/auto_logout/?r=<?php echo $return_link; ?>");`  I'm wondering if I need to encode the URL so the query string doesn't get dropped.

Comment: I added `urlencode` and `urldecode`and that seemed to do the trick.  Thank you for pointing me in the direction of thinking this through!